# sqlserver data to excel xlsx using php ? what wrong in this code..?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, php

```
<?php
    $serverName = '-'; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( 'Database'=>'-');
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn!='') {
       'Connection established.<br />';
    }else{
        'Connection could not be established.<br />';
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    /** Set default timezone (will throw a notice otherwise) */
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    // include PHPExcel
    require('../PHPExcel.php');
    // create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
    // set default font
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
    // set default font size
    $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);
    // create the writer
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
    /**
     * Define currency and number format.
     */
    // currency format, € with < 0 being in red color
    $currencyFormat = '#,#0.## \€;[Red]-#,#0.## \€';
    // number format, with thousands separator and two decimal points.
    $numberFormat = '#,#0.##;[Red]-#,#0.##';
    // writer already created the first sheet for us, let's get it
    $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    // rename the sheet
    $objSheet->setTitle('My sales report');
    // let's bold and size the header font and write the header
    // as you can see, we can specify a range of cells, like here: cells from A1 to A4
    $objSheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(12);
    // write header
    $objSheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('Name');
    $objSheet->getCell('B1')->setValue('phone No');
    // we could get this data from database, but here we are writing for simplicity
    $i = '2';
    $que=sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table");
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($que)){
        $name=$row['CustomerName'];
        $PhoneNo=$row['CustomerPhone'];
        $data[] = array(
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'empno'=>$PhoneNo
        );
    }
    $array = stripslashes(json_encode($data));
    $json = (object)json_decode($array);
    foreach($json AS $datas){
        $objSheet->getCell('A'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->name);
        $objSheet->getCell('B'.$i.'')->setValue($datas->empno);
    $i++;
    }
    // autosize the columns
    $objSheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objSheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
    //Setting the header type
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    /* If you want to save the file on the server instead of downloading, replace the last 4 lines by 
        $objWriter->save('test.xlsx');
    */
?>
```

Comment: This is not a question about databases, but a question about PHP.

Comment: check for errors via php and the query.

Comment: it's work when i use query for MySQL with php but when i am using query for sqlserver it's not working and show below error                                                   Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid